# Path integral in the extented complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis

For a simply connected domain, we know that the integral of an analytic function is path independent. Suppose we have such a function in the (extended) upper half plane. Do we have that the integral from some point $z_0\in \mathbb{H}$ to the point at infinity also path independent ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes - simply connected domains like this are equivalent via conformal maps, and path independence is a conformal property.